# $jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer escapes html. How can html in the labels be rendered correctly?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a regular bar chart with the only difference being that the tick labels are rotated as in the example of this documentation:

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php

Now, the chart works fine, until you get some html code into the label string that needs to be rendered as html - i'm talking mainly about html codes:

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

The code that i'm having particular problems is the **`&quot;`** which should render as **"**.

The encoding of html works fine with the pie chart and the bar chart in general, but adding the `tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer` seems to break the labels and create the problem described above with the **`&quot;`**.

Here's my example jqplot render script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1 = [['&quot;Cup Holder Pinion Bob&quot;', 7], ['Generic &quot;Fog&quot; Lamp', 9], ['HDTV Receiver', 15], 
  ['8 Track Control Module', 12], [' Sludge Pump Fourier Modulator', 3], 
  ['Transcender/Spice Rack', 6], ['Hair Spray Danger Indicator', 18]];

  var plot1 = $.jqplot('bar-test', [line1], {
    title: 'Concern vs. Occurrance',
    series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,escapeHTML: false}],
    seriesDefaults: {
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            escapeHTML: false
        }
    },
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        tickOptions: {
          angle: -30,
          fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I tried to make a jsfiddle, but am unsure how to load jqplot in there:   http://jsfiddle.net/6g7C6/

At least it gives the code structure.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me as it renders the `&quot` as ".
Look at the example i prepared for you: [Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ej8X7/1/)